# Connecting Android device to Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, python, raspberry-pi, uuid

I would like to connect my Raspberry pi to Android device , The Raspberry Pi broadcasts  following  UUIDs  ,

```
   UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
   UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
   UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
   UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
   UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
   Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0517
```

I would like to know which UUIDS i have to use in my code  to connect  Raspberry pi.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: Why google-glass tag?

Comment: @DavidCorral , i just used it as example, Android device can be any thing, could you please let me know how i could possibly connect Raspberry Pi UUID with  device